# How to determine cause of system crash?

Tags: linux, centos, server-crashes

My server crashes about once a week and does not leave any kind of clue as to what's causing it. I have checked `/var/log/messages` and it just stops recording at some point and starts at the computer post information when I perform a hard reboot.

Is there something I can check or software I can install that can determine the cause?

I'm running CentOS 7.

Here is the only error/problem in my `/var/log/dmesg`: https://paste.netcoding.net/cosisiloji.log

```
[    3.606936] md: Waiting for all devices to be available before autodetect
[    3.606984] md: If you don't use raid, use raid=noautodetect
[    3.607085] md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
[    3.608309] md: Scanned 6 and added 6 devices.
[    3.608362] md: autorun ...
[    3.608412] md: considering sdc2 ...
[    3.608464] md:  adding sdc2 ...
[    3.608516] md: sdc1 has different UUID to sdc2
[    3.608570] md:  adding sdb2 ...
[    3.608620] md: sdb1 has different UUID to sdc2
[    3.608674] md:  adding sda2 ...
[    3.608726] md: sda1 has different UUID to sdc2
[    3.608944] md: created md2
[    3.608997] md: bind<sda2>
[    3.609058] md: bind<sdb2>
[    3.609116] md: bind<sdc2>
[    3.609175] md: running: <sdc2><sdb2><sda2>
[    3.609548] md/raid1:md2: active with 3 out of 3 mirrors
[    3.609623] md2: detected capacity change from 0 to 98520989696
[    3.609685] md: considering sdc1 ...
[    3.609737] md:  adding sdc1 ...
[    3.609789] md:  adding sdb1 ...
[    3.609841] md:  adding sda1 ...
[    3.610005] md: created md1
[    3.610055] md: bind<sda1>
[    3.610117] md: bind<sdb1>
[    3.610175] md: bind<sdc1>
[    3.610233] md: running: <sdc1><sdb1><sda1>
[    3.610714] md/raid1:md1: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
[    3.610773] md/raid1:md1: active with 3 out of 3 mirrors
[    3.610854] md1: detected capacity change from 0 to 20970405888
[    3.610917] md: ... autorun DONE.
[    3.610999] md: resync of RAID array md1
[    3.611054] md: minimum _guaranteed_  speed: 1000 KB/sec/disk.
[    3.611119] md: using maximum available idle IO bandwidth (but not more than 200000 KB/sec) for resync.
[    3.611180] md: using 128k window, over a total of 20478912k.
[    3.611244]  md1: unknown partition table
[    3.624786] EXT3-fs (md1): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (240)
[    3.627095] EXT2-fs (md1): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (244)
[    3.630284] EXT4-fs (md1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    3.630341] EXT4-fs (md1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    3.819411] EXT4-fs (md1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    3.836922] EXT4-fs (md1): 24 orphan inodes deleted
[    3.836975] EXT4-fs (md1): recovery complete
[    3.840557] EXT4-fs (md1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Comment: I'd like to know too - I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04 machine that just stops responding from time to time and I have to physically reboot it when that happens. I haven't been able to figure out why it is the only machine I can access which keeps doing that...

Answer (score 10):

If you have `crashkernel/kdump` installed and enabled, you should be able to examine the crashed kernel with relative ease using the `crash` utility. For example, presuming that your crashed kernel dumps are saved under `/var/crash`:

```
crash /var/crash/2009-07-17-10\:36/vmcore \
      /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/`uname -r`/vmlinux`
```

Look at [Fedora's kdump debugging guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_use_kdump_to_debug_kernel_crashes) and [Red Hat's crashdump guide (PDF)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/Kernel_Crash_Dump_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Kernel_Crash_Dump_Guide-en-US.pdf) for added details.

Comment: I have repaired the `/dev/md1 not found` error when running `grub2-probe` and installed and configured crashkernel/kdump and will report back if/when it crashes again.

Answer (score 6):

You could check the dmesg file at `/var/log/dmesg`, which is logging the kernel messages. The messages log is just logging service and application messages and if you have a kernel error, the services and applications will just stop running, but the kernel error is still logged in dmesg.

Comment: I checked dmesg and dmesg.old, both only contain the startup information (about 4.8 seconds). The only "problem" I can see is the startup disk or raid drives appear to have something wrong but the system fixes it and works regardless. Check main post for link.

Answer (score 3):

- bios memory test
- bios hard drive test
- Check smart drive log `smartctl /dev/sda -a`
- Smart drive [tests](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_tests_with_smartctl)
- leave `dmesg -wH` running in a window

Comment: I've ran smart drive tests on all 3 drives, they are uncorrupted. I have `dmesg -wH` running in a window (I assume until it crashes again; and can still read the output after the crash over SSH). I do not have physical access to the machine, do I ask my host to run the bios memory and hard drive tests?